# Adding Two Numbers from Input

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to write this little program which accepts 2 integers and adds them and displays them to the user. I manage to write the entire program and save the variables (`number1`, `number2`), and now I have to store `number1 + number2` in `result`.

### Here's the code. Where does the add function go?

```
segment .data 

    msg db "Please enter a digit ", 0xA,0xD 
    len equ $ - msg 

segment .bss

    number1 resb 10 
    number2 resb 10 
    result resb 10    

segment .text 

    msg2 db "Please enter a second digit", 0xA,0xD 
    len2 equ $ - msg2 

    msg3 db "The sum is : ", 0xA,0xD 
    len3 equ $ - msg3

global _start 

 _start: 

    mov eax, 4         
    mov ebx, 1         
    mov ecx, msg         
    mov edx, len 
    int 0x80                

    mov eax, 3 
    mov ebx, 0  
    mov ecx, number1 
    mov edx, 10 
    int 0x80            

    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1         
    mov ecx, msg2          
    mov edx, len2         
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3  
    mov ebx, 0  
    mov ecx, number2 
    mov edx, 10 
    int 0x80        

    mov eax, 4         
    mov ebx, 1         
    mov ecx, msg3          
    mov edx, len3         
    int 0x80

    ;add result, number1
    ;add result, number2 

    mov eax, 4        
    mov ebx, 1 

    mov ecx, $result         
    mov edx, len3         
    int 0x80


exit:    
    mov eax, 1   
    xor ebx, ebx 
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Please format your code.  Instructions are on the post/edit page.

Comment: hey well i think i did it right this time , heres what i have for the add , 
mov eax, $number1
add eax, $number2
mov $result, eax
int 0x80 

but this doesnt work :S

Answer (score 1):

For a start, the digits you get from the input will be in ASCII, so you're going to need to subtract `'0'` from them to get the actual decimal value. For this case I'm assuming each number is 1 digit long and I've made the buffers 2 bytes in size (to read the digit + `'\n'`).

Once the numbers (single digits as stated) have been added, add `'0'` to the result to convert from decimal to ASCII. This will obviously only work for a result between 0-9; since this sounds like it might be homework I'm not going to add code that'll print numbers with multiple digits.

Anyway I've added a few lines to show you how to get started and neatened up some of your mess. You should really use equates for things like syscall numbers.

```
    SYS_EXIT  equ 1
    SYS_READ  equ 3
    SYS_WRITE equ 4
    STDIN     equ 0
    STDOUT    equ 1

segment .data 

    msg db "Please enter a digit ", 0xA,0xD 
    len equ $- msg 

segment .bss

    number1 resb 2 
    number2 resb 2 
    result resb 1    

segment .text 

    msg2 db "Please enter a second digit", 0xA,0xD 
    len2 equ $- msg2 

    msg3 db "The sum is: "
    len3 equ $- msg3

global _start 

 _start: 

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
    mov ebx, STDOUT         
    mov ecx, msg         
    mov edx, len 
    int 0x80                

    mov eax, SYS_READ 
    mov ebx, STDIN  
    mov ecx, number1 
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80            

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
    mov ebx, STDOUT         
    mov ecx, msg2          
    mov edx, len2         
    int 0x80

    mov eax, SYS_READ  
    mov ebx, STDIN  
    mov ecx, number2 
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80        

    mov eax, SYS_WRITE         
    mov ebx, STDOUT         
    mov ecx, msg3          
    mov edx, len3         
    int 0x80

    ; load number1 into eax and subtract '0' to convert from ASCII to decimal
    mov eax, [number1]
    sub eax, '0'
    ; do the same for number2
    mov ebx, [number2]
    sub ebx, '0'

    ; add eax and ebx, storing the result in eax
    add eax, ebx
    ; add '0' to eax to convert the digit from decimal to ASCII
    add eax, '0'

    ; store the result in result
    mov [result], eax

    ; print the result digit
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE        
    mov ebx, STDOUT
    mov ecx, result         
    mov edx, 1        
    int 0x80


exit:    
    mov eax, SYS_EXIT   
    xor ebx, ebx 
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Hey really thanks for your help , just to clarify this is not homework lol teachers dont give that kind of easy assignments im a university student just learning a new language , btw i increase the size of the buffer to 4 bytes but it still adds only single characters .... do i need to make a new ecx register and parse the ascii char in there and later concatenate "assume concatenation is easy with assembly"

Comment: Hey just figured it out :D i just increased the buffer size but here a question suppose my buffer size is 4 right and 1+1 =2$$$ , why do i get funny characters like that at the end of my answer is there any was to fix this ? but when i do 12 +12 = 24$$ ...

Comment: You're probably getting funny characters because you're printing out 4 characters when only two are digits and the others might be characters like the newline (`\n`), so when you're adding `'0'` to convert from decimal to ASCII you might also be doing it to the extra characters that aren't digits. Anyway, I'm not 100% sure you're adding or printing the numbers up right, if you're not there's a few questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884143/how-to-print-numbers-greater-then-10-in-arm200-assembly-language) that explain how to do so properly in ASM.