# Assembly code calculation of the GCD of two numbers is not working

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, x86-16

```
.MODEL small
.STACK 100h
.DATA
    A dw 0
    B dw 0
    C Dw 0
.CODE
MAIN PROC
    mov AX,@DATA
    mov DS,AX

PROMPT:
    mov AH,1
    int 21h
    mov A,Ax    
    mov AH,2
    mov DL,20H
    int 21H
    mov AH,1
    int 21h
    mov B,Ax
    mov AH,2
    mov DL,20H
    int 21H

    mov Ax,A
    ;sub AL,'0'
    mov Bx,B
    ;sub BL,'0'

    cmp Ax,Bx
    JE EXIT
    JA GCD 
    JB EXCG

GCD:
    MOV AH,0D
    DIV AL
    CMP AH,0D
    JE EXIT
    MOV Bx,Ax
    MOV bL,AL 
    JMP GCD

EXCG:
    MOV AH,0D
    XCHG Ax,Bx
    JMP GCD

 EXIT:
    MOV Dx,Ax
    MOV AH,2
    ;MOV DL,AL
    INT 21H

  MOV AH,4CH
  INT 21H

MAIN ENDP 
END MAIN
```

I expect the output would be the greatest common divisor of the two numbers.
but my code shows some ASCII value of unexpected characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this code correct (Number plus number, then print the result)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975848/is-this-code-correct-number-plus-number-then-print-the-result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> mov AH,1
> int 21h
> mov A,Ax
> ```

This DOS function returns a **character** in `AL`. You should not store the whole of `AX` as your first number! What you need is:

```
mov ah, 1
int 21h
sub al, '0'   ;Convert to a true number, no longer a character
mov A, al
```

Same for your second number.

---

> ```
> cmp Ax,Bx
> ```

Compare bytes here. Write `cmp al, bl`.

---

> ```
> MOV AH,0D
> DIV AL
> CMP AH,0D
> JE EXIT
> ```

It's fine to zero extend the dividend but think a moment about what `DIV AL` does. It will divide `AX` by `AL`. Since `AL` is just the low portion of `AX`, this division will always return a quotient of 1 with a 0 remainder. Not very useful because the EXIT will always be chosen.

---

> ```
> EXIT:
> MOV Dx,Ax
> MOV AH,2
> ;MOV DL,AL
> INT 21H
> ```

To display a result you have to convert it back into a character. You must add 48 to do this:

```
EXIT:
 mov dl, al
 add dl, '0'
 mov ah, 02h
 int 21h
```